# Limit in Laravel Datatable

Tags: php, datatable

I use a [Laravel Datatable](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables) in Laravel to create a Datatable. I need to show only 5 records, so i try this code.

```
   $visitas = Visita::select(['id','f_salida','f_entrada','nombre', 'empresa','visitado_id'])->orderBy('f_entrada', 'desc'); 
            ->setTotalRecords(5)
            -> make(true);
```

I set total records to show only 5, but datatable show all elements.

The question is: How can i put something like limit in the query to show only specific number of rows?

Answer (score 1):

You should used `->take(5)` to fetch only 5 recrds like this

```
$visitas = Visita::select(['id','f_salida','f_entrada','nombre', 'empresa','visitado_id'])
    ->orderBy('f_entrada', 'desc'); 
    ->take(5);
```

For more details about [Query Builder in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#selects)

Comment: @ElHombreSinNombre what is your laravel version?

Comment: Laravel 5.5. In your code you has a pure eloquent query, i need laravel datatable query, with ->make(true);

Comment: It doesn't work with Laravel Datatables, and rather throws error: 


BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2405:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getQuery()

Answer (score 0):

@El Hombre Sin Nombre, 
As per my understand you want to fetch only 5 records right, if I'm right you can use **take**

Something like this,

```
Fulls::orderBy(..)->take(5)->get();
```

Comment: @el-hombre-sin-nombr, is this helpful to you?

Comment: This doesn't work with Laravel Datatable package. I need to use it for click in th and order rows.

Comment: It doesn't work with Laravel Datatables, and rather throws error: 


BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2405:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getQuery()